# Select max of one column based on two other columns

Tags: sql-server, salesforce

I have a table with the following data:

```
id, foreign_id, contact, asset
```

There are many entries for the same contact with distinct foreign_ids, and what I am trying to do is get the `asset` value based on `max(id)`.

So let's imagine we have a set of data like this:

```
id: 1, foreign_id: 15, contact: email@email.com, asset: 1
id: 2, foreign_id: 15, contact: email@email.com, asset: 2
id: 2, foreign_id: 15, contact: email@email.com, asset: 2
id: 3, foreign_id: 14, contact: email@email.com, asset: 3
id: 4, foreign_id: 14, contact: emailTwo@email.com, asset: 1
id: 5, foreign_id: 15, contact: emailTwo@email.com, asset: 5
id: 6, foreign_id: 15, contact: emailTwo@email.com, asset: 12
```

I would like to write a query that returns this:

```
id: 2, foreign_id: 15, contact: email@email.com, asset: 2, share_number: 2
id: 3, foreign_id: 14, contact: email@email.com, asset: 3, share_number: 1
id: 4, foreign_id: 14, contact: emailTwo@email.com, asset: 1, share_number 1
id: 5, foreign_id: 15, contact: emailTwo@email.com, asset: 12, share_number: 2
```

As you can see, it gets the max asset for every contact for each foreign_id. Then I also want the `share_number` of each row with respect to a particular contact ordered by foreign_id.

This is written in Marketing Cloud's version of SQL Server. I cannot use any declarations or variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT id, foreign_id, contact, asset,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contact ORDER BY id) rn
FROM
(
    SELECT id, foreign_id, contact, asset,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foreign_id, contact ORDER BY asset DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

Your expected output does not seem to have any particular order, but you can easily impose one by adding a `GROUP BY` clause to my query.

**Edit:** I added another call to `ROW_NUMBER` in the outer query which numbers records sharing the same contact.  I assume that the ordering is given by the `id` column, but I'm not sure about that.  Replace `ORDER BY id` with whatever column you want to use.

Comment: If I wanted to know the ROW_NUMBER for the final query, I could add a 
```ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contact ORDER BY foreign_id ASC)```, yes?

Comment: No, just add `rn` to the outer select list, i.e. `SELECT id, foreign_id, ..., rn`

Comment: But that will give me the row number of the things that share a foreign_id and contact. I then want the row number of everything that shares the same contact.

Comment: @tonestrike Edit your question and show us what you want here.

Comment: Adding the ROW_NUMBER() as I mentioned did the trick. Thanks! You definitely answered the original question.